# how to chech the address that buys the highest amount on a contract

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

What is the process for identifying the address that has made the largest purchase amount within a specific contract?"

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of different methods to do this, but some methods can not be performed for all contracts.

First of all, you need to know that each contract has its own code, and its structure, so finding the highest received amount by a contract can depend on the contract itself.

1- You can use [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/) to explore the contract functions interactions and check for the highest received amount of ethers tx, then check the sender.

2- You can use Web3 API services, these services provide some functionalities to get data that is hard to be done manually. Some Web3 API providers: [moralis](https://moralis.io/), [alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/), and [Thirdweb](https://thirdweb.com/).

3- Some contracts have [event](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/solidity/solidity_events.htm) that can be queried to fetch data when a given function is fired, and the contract may have an event when a purchase happened.

4- There may be a function that fetches the highest purchase amount in the contract itself.

NOTE: these processes can be done if the contract accepts ethers, as I understand from your question.

Hope this was helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for this...

Comment: You are welcome. You can upvote the answer if it is helpful.